# Add data tot dataset and export to file

Tags: javascript, user-input

I have written a simple script to add data to a dataset (see below).

```
var dataset = [];
function addData(name,wlevel){
var tmpObj = new Object;
tmpObj.name = name;
tmpObj.wlevel = wlevel;
dataset.push(tmpObj);
}

addData("nmgn",12.1);
addData("mstr",24.8);

for(i=0 ; i < dataset.length ; i++){
document.write("<p>" + dataset[i].name + ": ");
document.write(dataset[i].wlevel + "</p>");
}
```

How can I let a user add data to the dataset and save or export it to a file? Is that even possible with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to files with JavaScript.

Comment: Ok thank you. So I have to find another way to accomplish my goal.